# Where are these Lord Shiva stotras and mantras from?

Tags: vedas, shiva, shaivism, source

There are many popular songs with these lyrics, the first one seems to be called Namaskaratha Mantra. What is the meaning if Namaskaratha? And where all these stotras and mantras from? Also these shlokas seem to have spelling mistakes, so please link to the correct version.

> ॐ नमो हिरण्यबाहवे हिरण्यवर्णाय, हिरण्यरूपाय हिरण्यपतए । अंबिका पतए उमा
> पतए पशूपतए नमो नमः॥
>
> ईशान सर्वविद्यानाम् ईश्वर सर्व भूतानाम् । ब्रह्मादीपते ब्रह्मनोदिपते,
> ब्रह्मा शिवो अस्तु सदा शिवोहम्॥
>
> तत्पुरुषाय विद्महे वागविशुद्धाय धिमहे, तन्नो शिव प्रचोदयात्।
>
> महादेवाय विद्महे रुद्रमूर्तये धिमहे, तन्नों शिव प्रचोदयात्॥
>
> नमस्ते अस्तु भगवान विश्वेश्वराय, महादेवाय त्र्यंबकाय त्रिपुरान्तकाय।
> त्रिकाग्नी कालाय कालाग्नी रुद्राय, नीलकंठाय मृत्युंजयाय सर्वेश्वराय॥
> सदशिवाय श्रीमन्महादेवाय नमः शांतिः शांतिः शांतिः

[Source](https://kivabeguide.com/namaskaratha-mantra-lyrics/?expand_article=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *namo hiraNyabaahave hiraNyavarNaaya hiraNyaruupaaya hiraNyapataye.ambikaapataya |
> umaapataye pashupataye namo namaH | (Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.22.1).*
>
> *Salutations again and again to the Golden armed, to the the golden hued One, whose form is resplendent like Gold, who is the Lord of Gold, who is the Lord of Ambika, of Uma, who is the Lord of Pashus.”*

> *iishaanaH sarvavidyaanaamiishvaraH sarvabhuutaanaaM |
> brahmaadhipatirbrahmaNo.adhipatirbrahmaa shivo me astu sadaashivom.h | (Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.21.1).*
>
> *May the Supreme who is the ruler of all knowledge, controller of all created beings, the preserver of the Vedas and the one overlord of Hiranyagarbha, be benign to me. I am the Sadasiva described thus and denoted by Pranava.*

> *"Namaste astu bhavagan vishvesvaraya mahadevaya triyambakaya triupurantakaya trikalAgni kalaya kalagni Rudraya nilakanthaya mrutyunjayaya sarveshvaraya sadashivaya sriman mahadevaya Namah" (Yajurveda Sri Rudram – Anuvaka -1).*
>
> *"Let my salutations be to that great God who is the Lord of the universe; the great God whohas three eyes and who destroys Tripura, the three Asura cities. To that God who is the Sandhya time when the three sacred fires are lit; who is Rudra the fire that consumes the universe; whose throat is blue; who has conquered death; the Lord of all; the ever auspicious one; salutations to that glorious and great God."*

Could not find the reference for the two Gayatri Mantras. Will see later on.

> *तत्पुरुषाय विद्महे वागविशुद्धाय धिमहे, तन्नो शिव प्रचोदयात्।*
>
> *महादेवाय विद्महे रुद्रमूर्तये धिमहे, तन्नों शिव प्रचोदयात्॥*
>
> *We meditate upon the Supreme Being, who is the purifier of speech, May He inspire and enlighten our minds, may He lead us towards Shiva.*
>
> *We meditate upon the Great God, who is the embodiment of Rudra, May He inspire and enlighten our minds, may He lead us towards Shiva.*

I hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you

Comment: You are most Welcome. ..

Answer (score 1):

Many lines are from the Sri Rudram or Shatarudriya.
Some lines , I have not seen before but maybe due to a different redaction or shakha.

Comment: Namaste welcome to HSE. While on the site, you can go through the help centre as well as Guidelines for new users answering. The rules insist on deriving the answer based on scriptures or great acharyas. Hope you have a good time on the site :)

Comment: Thank you for your most kind namaste and welcome. I apologise for the delay in thanking you, as was focussing on improving. There is great wisdom as you mentioned, in deriving it from the maha acharyas.